# RProvider does not locate package ggplot2

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have installed 'ggplot2' using

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

on the R Console.

On F# side,

```
open RProvider.ggplot2
```

is not able to locate the namespace.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS after installing the package?

Comment: Uhm. There was a problem on my side. I re-installed the RTypeProvider from nuget and now works.

Comment: Well, the problem comes and goes. I don't see any pattern. Sometimes restarting Visual Studio helps. Is there a log file I can check?

Comment: install.packages("ggplot2") did the trick for me, thanks, I had the same problem